# How to extract list of dictionaries from Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe that I extracted from an API, inside that df there is a column that I need to extract data from it, but the structure of that data inside that column is a list of dictionaries:

[image]

I could get the data that I care from that dictionary using this chunk of code:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    for i,j in v.items():
        if isinstance(j, list):
            for l in range(len(j)):
                for k in j[l]:
                    print(j[l])
```

I get a structure like this one, so I´d need to get each of that 'values' inside the list of dictionaries

[image]

and then organize them in a dataframe. like for example the first item on the list of dictionaries:

[image]

Once I get to the point of getting the above structure, how could I make a dataframe like the one in the image?

Raw data:

```
data = {'rows': [{'values': ['Tesla Inc (TSLA)', '$1056.78', '$1199.78', '13.53%'], 'children': []}, {'values': ['Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing Company Limited (TSM)', '$120.31', '$128.80', '7.06%'], 'children': []}]}
```

Comment: These would be the first 2 items in that list of dicts: {'rows': [{'values': ['Tesla Inc (TSLA)', '$1056.78', '$1199.78', '13.53%'], 'children': []}, {'values': ['Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing Company Limited (TSM)', '$120.31', '$128.80', '7.06%'], 'children': []}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas`. First cast your data to `pd.DataFrame`, then use `apply(pd.Series)` to expand lists inside `'values'` column to separate columns and `set_axis` method to change column names:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'rows': [{'values': ['Tesla Inc (TSLA)', '$1056.78', '$1199.78', '13.53%'], 'children': []}, {'values': ['Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing Company Limited (TSM)', '$120.31', '$128.80', '7.06%'], 'children': []}]}
out = pd.DataFrame(data['rows'])['values'].apply(pd.Series).set_axis(['name','price','price_n','pct'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                                                    name     price   price_n     pct
    0                                   Tesla Inc (TSLA)  $1056.78  $1199.78   13.53%  
    1  Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing Company Lim...   $120.31   $128.80    7.06%
```